# Geographical Representation of TimeZones

Tags: geographics

I'm trying to show a geographical representation of a TimeZone on a map.

On the Mathematica website, it says I can use Polygon[] and it will automatically color in that TimeZone region on a map:[image: Code from wolfram.com]

```
GeoGraphics[{Red, EdgeForm[Black], 
  Polygon[Entity["TimeZone", "America/Denver"]]}, 
 GeoRange -> Quantity[100, "Miles"]]
```

However, when I run the same exact code myself, it doesn't work.[image: Code ran on my laptop]
I've looked all over the internet for possible solutions, but I couldn't find any. I have also tried restarting the application and running it on a second laptop, both failed to fix the problem. Does anyone know what's going on?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a link to the website that you are referencing. Also include your code rather than just a picture of the code.

Comment: It looks like that data is now missing on the wolfram knowledgebase. If you do (for example) `Entity["TimeZone", "America/Phoenix"]["Dataset"]`, you'll see that `polygon` has the value `$Failed`. It seems like a bug so you should report it to WRI if you can!